# function is returning undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function in javascript expression to check if the result is true or false but i am always getting undefined error

```js
var array = [{
    email: 'usman@gmail.com',
    password: '123'
  },
  {
    email: 'ali@gmail.com',
    password: '123'
  }
];

let main = function(email, password) {

  return array.forEach((row) => {
    if (row.email === email && row.password === password) {
      return true

    } else {
      return false
    }
  });

};

var checkLogin = main('usman@gmail.com', '123');
console.log(checkLogin)
```

checkLogin always return undefined

Comment: Why are you returning the forEach loop?

Comment: `array.forEach` doesn't return anything.  I think you meant to use `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a problem with foreach. it doesn't return anything

```
var array = [
{email: 'mike@gmail.com', password: '123'},
];

let main = function(email, password) {

   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if (array[i].email === email && array[i].password === password) {
    return true
     } 
       };
      return false
     };

   var checkLogin = main('mike@gmail.com', '123');
   console.log(checkLogin) // returns true
```

Comment: btw, this works only with the given array order, but not if the wanted part is the second element of `array`. you need to move `return false` to the end of the function, not inside of the `for` statement, because this ends the iteration with the first element.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `forEach` does not return anything. You can use simple for-loop, like this:

```js
var array = [
{email: 'usman@gmail.com', password: '123'},
{email: 'ali@gmail.com', password: '123'}
];

let main = function(email, password) {

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var row = array[i];
        if (row.email === email && row.password === password) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
};

var checkLogin = main('usman@gmail.com', '123');
console.log(checkLogin)
```

Also, take a look at [`some()`](http://var%20array%20=%20[%20%7Bemail:%20'usman@gmail.com',%20password:%20'123'%7D,%20%7Bemail:%20'ali@gmail.com',%20password:%20'123'%7D%20];%20%20let%20main%20=%20function(email,%20password)%20%7B%20%20return%20array.forEach((row)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20if%20(row.email%20===%20email%20&&%20row.password%20===%20password)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%7D;%20%20var%20checkLogin%20=%20main('usman@gmail.com',%20'123');%20console.log(checkLogin)), [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: btw, this works only with the given array order, but not if the wanted part is the second element of `array`. you need to move `return false` to the end of the function, not inside of the `for` statement, because this ends the iteration with the first element.

Answer (score 2):

The `forEach` array function doesn't return anything. If you touch looped array inside it then you are able to modify existing array without copying it.

Comment: It *loops over* the array.  It doesn't necessarily modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

there is something wrong with this logic:

```
return array.forEach((row) => {
if (row.email === email && row.password === password) {
  return true

} else {
  return false
}
});
```

without this logic it returns anything you want

Comment: forEach doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and return the result of the check.

```js
var array = [{ email: 'ali@gmail.com', password: '123' }, { email: 'usman@gmail.com', password: '123' }];

let main = (email, password) =>
        array.some(row => row.email === email && row.password === password);

var checkLogin = main('usman@gmail.com', '123');
console.log(checkLogin)
```